# Android app title bar doesn't show when testing the app?

Tags: android, rendering, titlebar

I'm creating an app, and when I build it and start it on my phone (a Sony Xperia Z1 with Android 4.4.4), the title bar doesn't show. All activities is rendered without the title bar, like this:

[image]

I'm using Android Studio, and in the editor, the title bar is visible. It just don't work when the app is being ran.

All help with this is appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the android theme statement from the manifest and also the xml from styles.xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update to this answer. ActionBarActivity was deprecated as of version 22.1.0. To achieve this same outcome, extend AppCompatActivity.

[ActionBarActivity API Class Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Comment: You can also use the `ActionBarActivity` in the appcompat library.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer. Each of my `Activity` classes extended `Activity`, and when changing that to `ActionBarActivity`, the action bar (called "title bar" by me) shows up. I changed those values when I created the classes, because I "was sure" that in all my other projects, the classes extended just `Activity`, and not `ActionBarActivity`, but I "was sure wrong".

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not on my computer, so I can't link it, but go to your styles.xml and make sure there is nothing that says NoActionBar.